# Creating a custom login form with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to get the custom login form to work with Spring Security 3.0.

The default login form works fine with the security configuration below.  Then I added the form-login attribute, created the login controller and jsp page to handle the /accounts/logIn URL and now have this problem:  when I enter my guest/guest credentials, I am sent back to the logIn page.

One thing I noticed in the catalina.out log is that the successful check is looking at /j_security_check, whereas the unsuccessful one is looking at /accounts/j_security_check.

Here's my security-config.xml:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/accounts/logIn" /><!--ADDED THIS AFTER TESTING DEFAULT LOGIN-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/accounts/logIn" access="permitAll()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
 <user-service>
            <user authorities="ROLE_USER" name="guest" password="guest"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Here is the section of catalina.out that looks relevant:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - Candidate is: '/accounts/j_spring_security_check'; pattern is /**; matched=true
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest at position 1 of 10 in additional filter\
 chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@8cbb423'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.sessi\
on.StandardSessionFacade@4679cf8c. A new one will be created.
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest at position 2 of 10 in additional filter\
 chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5d49453c'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest at position 3 of 10 in additional filter\
 chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@756095fc'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest at position 4 of 10 in additional filter\
 chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@18170f98'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest at position 5 of 10 in additional filter\
 chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@1200d083'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest - pathInfo: both null (property equals)
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest - queryString: arg1=null; arg2=j_username=guest&j_password=guest (property not equals)
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache - saved request doesn't match
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest at position 6 of 10 in additional filter\
 chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@737951b0'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest at position 7 of 10 in additional filter\
 chain; firing Filter: 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@49c06a6d'
DEBUG: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.secur\
ity.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faaf9b0: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.securit\
y.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff8868: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 0560416CA2D07AFF3040E75867157A95; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANON\
YMOUS'
```

Answer (score 4):

What should be happening is that your form should capture the user name and password and do a POST to the `j_spring_security_check` entry point the credentials as parameters; e.g.

```
/accounts/j_spring_security_check?j_username=guest&j_password=guest
```

This is then supposed to check them, and if they are correct, add the details to the user's session and redirect back to the page that the user was trying to access in the first place.

However, it looks like the request to the `j_spring_security_check` URL is being redirected by the filter chain.

I can think of two possible causes:

1. The security check URL `"/accounts/j_spring_security_check"` might not be right.  You could try `"/j_spring_security_check"` instead.
2. The `<intercept-url>` elements have been configured so that requests to the security check URL require some authorities.  (In this case, the catch-all element for the `"/**"` seems to be the problem.)  That is incorrect.  You need to configure the `<intercept-url>` elements to allow requests to the security check URL when the requestor is anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the log in page is redirecting you back to the login page. You can use the `default-target-url` attribute on the `form-login` element to specify where the page is to go after login.

For example,

`<form-login default-target-url="/accounts/home" login-page="accounts/logIn" />`